# How to pull and push data from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am working on a Crowdfunding app like change.org. I basically want to let user save data like image, reason for crowd fund and details and show it to all users of app. I want to use firebase as backend. I want to know is there any resource or a right direction anyone can point me to for learning it.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/ there you have everything. Please read how to ask questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also these https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/ https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Writing Data**

```
  Future<void> addUser() {
    // Create a CollectionReference called users that references the firestore collection
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
    return users
        .add({
          'full_name': fullName, // John Doe
          'company': company, // Stokes and Sons
          'age': age // 42
        })
        .then((value) => print("User Added"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
  }
```

**Reading data**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage